# Please can someone explain me these commands about python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> for n in range(2, 10):
...     for x in range(2, n):
...         if n % x == 0:
...             print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
...             break
...     else:
...         # loop fell through without finding a factor
...         print(n, 'is a prime number')
...
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
4 equals 2 * 2
5 is a prime number
6 equals 2 * 3
7 is a prime number
8 equals 2 * 4
9 equals 3 * 3
```

I don't understand what the above command wants to do.
I know about looping but can you explain what this command is actually doing?

Comment: Can you spend some time & read the Python documentation ?

Comment: What's the background? Are you reading a book? An article? Or just looking at a friend's code? Help us understand. We can't actually teach you how to code python, but we can help you learn. (If I answered your question literally, it would be "two loops over generated collections, a divisibility test, breaking out of the loop, and a really really nifty `for/else` construct that I forgot existed".)

Comment: actually i found this code on the internet. i was confused about the coding, what it was actually meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `for` and `while` loops have a feature that may look confusing to people who are more familiar with those loops in other programming languages: You can put an `else` clause after the loop body.

The `else` block will be run only if the loop terminated in the normal way (a for loop reaching the end of the iterable or a while loop's condition being false). It will not be run if the loop was terminated by a `break` statement.

In the code you're looking at, the inner loop tests to see if the number `n` is prime by testing if it can be evenly divided by any `x` value. If an `x` does divide it exactly, the factors `x` and `n // x` are printed and a `break` statement ends the loop.

If no such factor is found in the `range`, the loop ends. As I mentioned above, this the situation where the `else` block is run. It prints that `n` is prime.

Comment: Thnx for your help.you really helped me out of this .